# OpenCV - Array of Images, or Buffer of Mat

Tags: arrays, image, opencv, buffer

How, can I have a buffer or array of images "Mat" with OpenCV?

I mean: having a set of images, want to pick up and put in an array like

How can I do this? It's like C++ normal array style?

```
 Mat images[2];

    images[0] = imread(...);
    images[1] = imread(..);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything before asking it here ?

Comment: Sorry , I didn't downvote !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just declare a array of cvMat object as-

```
Mat image_array[10];      // array of 10 images
```

Now read the images into it according to index of the array

```
image_array[0]=imread("/home/me/Pictures/img1.png",1);
image_array[1]=imread("/home/me/Pictures/img2.png",1);
......
......
image_array[9]=imread("/home/me/Pictures/img9.png",1);
```

Comment: This work? Simple assegnation? For recall every image, how can I  do it? Like imshow("image",image_array[7])  ??

Comment: exactly. image_array[7] represents 8'th image of the image array.

Comment: can I declare array size dynamically like this ? Mat image_array[var];

Comment: Dynamically I don't try. But at this point, if you don't know the size (for cicling) try to use other type of collections, like list, construct the list before and then, cicle over it with a foreach iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I had to implement something similar and I didn't need to view the images all I wanted was to extract some data from them but I'm going to add the imread anyway. Here is the code:

```
Mat mat[10];enter code here
char c[n]; //n is the size of chars in the directory of images

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
 sprintf(c,"/directory to images/%d.jpg",i);
 mat[i] = imread(c);
 imshow("mat",mat[i]);
 waitKey(0);
}
```

this is going to display the first image in the array and you will have to press any key to go to the next one. Hope this helps