# Creating a 2D array of matrices in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, matrix, g++

I'm trying to implement the SIFT algorithm from scratch. Right now, I'm attempting to generate the scale space, which contains multiple blurred images that decrease in scale. My instinct was use arrays because I knew the dimensions I needed and they were not subject to change. In the 2D array each element is a matrix that represents a blurred image. Each column would represent an octave. However, either OpenCV (version 2.4) or g++ doesn't seem to understand what I want. I'm using header and implementation files, however, the SIFT algorithm doesn't lend itself well to objects (IMO), so I am avoiding them.
Here's my code for the header file:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void generateOctaves(cv::Mat img); // Function to generate octaves.
void approxLoG(cv::Mat passOctave[4][5]);    // Function to approximate Laplacian of Gaussian
```

Here is the code of the corresponding implementation file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "scaleSpace.h"

// Generate four octaves with five images each.
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
void generateOcatves(Mat img)       // Determine Octaves
{
    Mat octaves[4][5];  // Creates 4x5 array/grid to hold 4 octaves, each comprised of 5 images.
    Mat resizedImg; // Holds resized image.
    resize(img, resizedImg, Size(), 2, 2, CV_INTER_CUBIC);      // Double image size to allow for more keypoints
    Mat originalResize = resizedImg;     // Temp matrix to hold the original resized image prior to blurring.
    double sigma = 1.6;     // General value for sigma
    double k = sqrt(2);     // Gneral value for k
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(i > 0)       // Shrink image on all iterations other than the first.
        {
            resize(originalResize, resizedImg, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, CV_INTER_AREA);
            // Reset altered values.
            originalResize = resizedImg;
            sigma = 1.6;
        }
        for(int j=0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            octaves[i][j] = resizedImg;
            GaussianBlur(resizedImg, resizedImg, Size(0,0), sigma, sigma, 0);   // Perform Gaussian Blur on the image.
            sigma = sigma * k;
            imshow("Octave", resizedImg);
        }
        cout << "Press Enter to continue." << endl;
        while (true)
        {
            char cont=(char)waitKey(25);
            if(cont == 27)
            {
                destroyAllWindows();
                break;
            }
        }
        approxLoG(octaves[4][5]);
    }
}

void approxLoG(Mat passOctave[4][5])
{
    // Compute the DoG of consecutive scales. Computing the DoG gives an approximation of the LoG in less time. 
    // Since the LoG would have to be computed for multiple images, the DoG is used.
    Mat array_DoG[4][4];    // 4x4 array to hold four octaves and 4 DoG images. There is one less DoG created than images in each octave for each octave.
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            Mat DoG = passOctave[i][j] - passOctave[i][j+1];        // Compute DoG
            imshow("Difference of Gaussian", DoG);
            array_DoG[i][j] = DoG;
        }
        char cont=(char)waitKey(25);
        if(cont == 27)
        {
            destroyAllWindows();
        }
    }
}
```

The compilation error I get is:

```
g++ -g -c scaleSpace.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv2`
scaleSpace.cpp: In function ‘void generateOcatves(cv::Mat)’:
scaleSpace.cpp:50:26: error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘cv::Mat (*)[5]’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void approxLoG(cv::Mat (*)[5])’
approxLoG(octaves[4][5]);
```

What particularly confuses me is that creating a 1D array of matrices can be done using OpenCV, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383672/opencv-array-of-images-or-buffer-of-mat).
I could probably use a 2D vector instead of an array. But, even so, why does a 2D array not work, but a 1D array does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line:

```
approxLoG(octaves[4][5]);
```

`octaves[4][5]` as every other `octaves[i][j]` is accessing a single element. This one being out of bounds.

To pass the array, just write:

```
approxLoG(octaves);
```

Comment: I'm still confused on how octaves is out of bounds. Is each element of octaves not a matrix? I looked at my for loop logic and it appears to be within the proper bounds to me. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @SaulKapruac Remember indexes are within 0 to size-1, size is off limits. {0, 1, 2, 3} for `i` and {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} for `j`. Higher values like `octaves[i=4][j=5]` are out of bounds.

Comment: Yes, but my conditions are while i and j are less than 4 and 5, respectively. Therefore, the for loop would stop iterating when those numbers are reached and the less than condition is no longer satisfied.

Comment: @SaulKapruac I'm talking about your call: `approxLoG(octaves[4][5]);`. Your for loops are fine.